# Limit display object's drag coordinates in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates, hierarchy, stage, displayobject

how can i reference a display object's coordinates according to it's parent object or stage from within the class that creates the object?

essentially when i create a new sprite object from a custom class and add it to the display list, i'd like to include code within the custom class that limits the drag coordinates to the stage, or a section of the stage.

```
//Frame Script
import Swatch;

var test:Sprite = new Swatch();
addChild(test);

___________________

//Custom Class
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Swatch extends Sprite
    {
    public function Swatch()
        {
        init();
        }

    private function init():void
        {
        var swatchObject:Sprite = new Sprite();

        swatchObject.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1);
        swatchObject.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 150, 150);
        swatchObject.graphics.endFill();

        swatchObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrag, false, 0, true);
        swatchObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop, false, 0, true);

        this.addChild(swatchObject);
        }

    private function onDrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        evt.target.startDrag();
        //how to limit it's dragability to the Stage?

        }

    private function onDrop(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        evt.target.stopDrag();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to listen for the Event.MOUSE_LEAVE event (attach `onDrop` to it), in case the user clicks on the object and let's go off-stage (although perhaps this is built-in to the `startDrag()` functionality already?). Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Stage.html#event:mouseLeave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some native support for what you want to do. `startDrag()` accepts a rectangle as a parameter which restricts the region in which the drag can take place.

```
function startDrag(lockCenter:Boolean  = false, bounds:Rectangle  = null):void
```

Hope that helps,

Tyler.

Comment: ok, so the second parameter of startDrag is what i'm looking for.  how do i reference the stage from my object?  i tried including flash.display.Stage, and then trace(this.parent.stage.stageWidth) but it gave an error.

Comment: as long as you are on the display list, you can just say "stage.stageWidth", you don't need to import it

Comment: ok i figured it out.  i had to create an event listener for ADDED_TO_STAGE in my constructor targeting the init() function, otherwise stage was null when i tried referencing it.  forgot about that pitfall.